# How to generate automatic makefile from Eclipse IDE without GUI

Tags: makefile, eclipse-plugin

I want to generte the makefile automatically for entire project from eclipse IDE without using GUI from command prompt. I am using eclipse CDT.

Is there any **eclipse plugin** or **eclipse api** from which I can do this without using eclipse GUI.

Comment: You can use [Eclipse Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/) to do builds using Maven.

Comment: There is command line utility available for eclipse to build project from command line without using GUI.

(https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/09/12/building-projects-with-eclipse-from-the-command-line/)

follow above link for more details